# How to compare the list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

Here i am having two lists :

```
list1 = ['2C535EB58F19B58' , '7B89D9071EB531B143594FF909BAC846' , '0509']

list2 = ['1641AB0C9C5B8867' , '0098968C' , '509']
```

I need to compare the elements inside list2 with list1 elements.

I want the output to be , after comparing :

```
509
```

since 509 is present in 0509.

How can i achieve so ? Does regex can help me in this ?

Comment: initialize a `res` list for the results, loop over `list1` and `list2` and check with an `if` statement for membership (`in`). If `True` `append` to `res`.

Comment: `[x for x in list2 if any(y for y in list1 if x in y)]` ?

Comment: Are you comparing elements per indices or if present at all in the list? does it just have to be a substring of one of them? What if list1's element is a substring of list2s? what have you tried?

Comment: @BearBrown yes this works perfectly. thanks

Comment: @EbinDavis you should answer the comment of the Sayse

Comment: `set.intersection(set(list1),set(list2))`

Comment: what about , 

`def Diff(li1, li2):
...     return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))`

`print(Diff(list1, list2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
common_elements = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if y in x:
            common_elements.append(y)
```

`common_elements` will contain the elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Here we are checking whether element in list2 is a substring of an element in list1.

```
list1 = ['2C535EB58F19B58' , '7B89D9071EB531B143594FF909BAC846' , '0509']

list2 = ['1641AB0C9C5B8867' , '0098968C' , '509']

for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    if j in i:
        print(j)
```

One-liner which will append to a list:

```
print( [j for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if j in i])
```

There could be more simple and better answers. If it helps, you can opt it.

Answer (score 0):

As already proposed by BearBrown in a comment, there is an easy way to achieve your goal. There is no reason to think about regular expressions at all (the `in`-operator is powerful enough).

```
[x for x in list2 if any(y for y in list1 if x in y)]
```

Here you are looking for each string `x` in list2 if it is a substring of any string `y` in list1 and finally save each matching substring `x` in a new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in list2:
    for y in list1:
        if x in y:
            print x #or whatever
```

nested for-loops, I think this is a simple way, but I'm sure there is a better one

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `in` operation in python to check whether one string is in another string.

The easiest way to solve your problem would be

```
[y for y in list2 if any(y in x for x in list1)]
```